# CommandButton: Change the buttons bgcolor on click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not at all familiar with Excel. Though I want one function that's pretty complicated to achieve for a first timer as me.

I want a button that changes color on each click.

I'll explain it in detail:

As standard the button has a Red bg color.
When I single-click the button the bg turns Yellow.
When I single-click the button again the bg color turns from Yellow to Green.
And on the next click it turns red again.

I have created a CommandButton and reached this, but here's where I don't seem to exactly figure out how to do.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
CommandButton1.BackColor = 5243047
CommandButton1.BackColor = 14150650
End Sub
```

I've tried different thing but none of my ideas are working.

It just turns to the color that row 3 are saying. Nothing changes on click.

Comment: Please note that I've not focused on the correct color-id yet. Just threw two different ones in there while testing out the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With CommandButton1
        Select Case .BackColor
            Case vbRed
                .BackColor = vbYellow
            Case vbYellow
                .BackColor = vbGreen
            Case vbGreen
                .BackColor = vbRed
            Case Else ' perhaps not needed, sets default to red
                .BackColor = vbRed
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```